# Install docker.io on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, docker

According to this:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver

I should be able to install Docker using:

`apt install docker.io`

However, as root, I get:

```
apt install docker.io
No command 'apt' found, did you mean:
 Command 'aptd' from package 'aptdaemon' (main)
```

Comment: try using `apt-get` instead of `apt`